# Mplayer slow to play network stream

Tags: linux, mplayer

I am using `mplayer` to play a network stream. It works quite well, but there is significant lag before starting up. For example, the following command takes about 5s to start playing.

```
mplayer -loop 0 https://justjazz.stream.laut.fm/justjazz
```

If I open that URL in the browser, then it starts playing almost immediately. Is there any way I can get this to play any quicker? I have gone through the man page and I could not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get this to play any quicker?

With Mplayer, I believe the answer is "it's unlikely". There could be some hidden settings somewhere, but in my experience, it simply takes a moment to start up. Alternatively, you may want to try [MPV](https://mpv.io/). It's (technically) an Mplayer fork and seems to generally start with less delay:

```
mpv https://justjazz.stream.laut.fm/justjazz
```

Comment: That's great thank you, and I tested it. It does seem like a nicer all round interface than mplayer, and buffering on disconnect even works out of the box it seems. However when it reconnects it dies shortly after and exits with an error. Is there an equivalent of `-loop 0` for `mpv`? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about it.

Comment: I tried `--loop-playlist=inf` and it still exits with errors. Great suggestion but it looks like I will just have to live with the delay.

Comment: Maybe try `--loop-playlist=force`? According to the [latest docs](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-loop-playlist) *"the force mode is like `inf`, but does not skip playlist entries which have been marked as failing. This means the player might waste CPU time trying to loop a file that doesn't exist. But it might be useful for playing webradios under very bad network conditions."* But beyond that, yeah, `mplayer` may be the better option.

Comment: That works great! Thank you! And even if it didn't, I learned about a seemingly better alternative to `mplayer`. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Genuinely glad to hear it worked for you.  =)